# Use DirectoryIndex while grant access only for one file

Tags: apache-2.4

I wanted to grant access only to index.php via .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Require all denied
<Files "/index.php">
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

That works, but when I open only the directory, it shows "403 Forbidden". How can I make DirectoryIndex work?

Comment: You specified `Require all denied` so of course it is blocked. Why have you put that there?

Comment: Because, I want to grant access only to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

Perhaps you could do something more sensible as redirecting everything not index.php to another directory and deny there.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RedirectMatch ^/(?!index\.php$|$)(.*) /test/$1
```

Comment: @levi-jcbs thanks for the edit!